# Regex to grab group of numbers

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have been working for a few hours on how to write a regex for a bash script that will only grab a group of more than 2 numbers. For example, if I had #jk2478_0.JPEG, I would only want to return 2478. I can return all of the numbers, but can't figure how to not include the 0 in the result for this example. Here is what I have so far.

```
i='#jk2478_0.JPEG';
f=`echo $i | sed s/[^0-9]*[^0-9]//g`
echo $f #24780
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '#jk2478_0.JPEG,' | grep -E -o '[0-9]{2,}'
2478
```

`-o` means match only

Answer (score 1):

Other way using sed

```
echo '#jk2478_0.JPEG,' | sed -re 's/(.*)([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)(.*)/\3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this?

```
f=`echo $i | sed s/.*([0-9]\{2,\}.*/\1/`
```